# Provide Values for x in R for ts.plot

Tags: r, plot

I am currently trying to set the x axis to the range -400 1000. I have a sample rate of 250 Hz, which equals 350 sample points to represent the 1400 ms range. Thus, I have 350 values and the x axis in the plot is basically indicating the "case num".

Using `ts.plot` (and not ggplot) how can I set the x axis to these values?

```
file = 'Z:/location/location/file.csv'
cdaheog <- read.csv(file, header = FALSE, na.strings = 0)

## Import Header
cdaheader <- read.csv('Z:/location/location/file.csv/Header.txt', header = TRUE, na.strings = 'null')
names(cdaheog) <- names(cdaheader)

tsRainbow <- rainbow(ncol(cdaheog))


## Flip axis
x <- range(cdaheog, na.rm = TRUE)

##Butterfly plot
ts.plot(cdaheog, col = tsRainbow, ylim = rev(range(x)))


##Get Sub Plots
d <- cdaheog

subjects = c(1, 3, 4, 6:11, 16:18, 20, 21)

L <- layout(matrix(c(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14), nrow=2, ncol=7, byrow = TRUE))
layout.show(L)

for(subject in subjects){

    a1 <- paste('s', subject, sep='')

    i2 <- paste(a1, '2', sep = '_item') 
    i4 <- paste(a1, '4', sep = '_item')
    i8 <- paste(a1, '8', sep = '_item')

    subject_output <- d[, names(d) %in% c(i2, i4, i8)]
    y <- range(cdaheog, na.rm = TRUE)
    tsRainbow <- rainbow(ncol(subject_output))
    ts.plot(subject_output, col = tsRainbow, ylim = rev(range(y))))

}
```

I have found that the following functions might be relevant, but have not been succesful in applying them:

```
`axis()`
```

For plot there is:

```
`plot(, xaxp=c(...))`
```

The code below did not work, clears the plots and replaces them with numbers:

```
axis(1, at=seq(0,350,25), labels=seq(-400,1000,100))
```

---

**Example Data**

```
s1_item2    s1_item4 s1_item8
1  0.36309  0.67705  -0.3969100
2  0.78652  0.51850  -0.0901100

...

...

349   -1.7256  -1.50100   -3.1980
350   -1.2201  -0.21089   -2.7908
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the xlim=c(-400, 1000) parameter to the ts.plot command?